# React native admob

Tags: react-native, admob

Hi guys im using the library for react native admob, however does anyone know how I can enable people to click on an ad through a button. For example enter full screen on a video I would like to implement an ad press on that. Although, how do I go about doing that? so far the library on gives code to display ad banner.

https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob

```
<AdMobBanner
  adSize="fullBanner"
  adUnitID="your-admob-unit-id"
  testDevices={[AdMobBanner.simulatorId]}
  onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are called rewarded video ads. Not banners. To do what you want the code looks something like this:

```
// Set up the rewarded ad
AdMobRewarded.setAdUnitID('your-admob-unit-id');
AdMobRewarded.requestAd()

....

// Start the video ad
setTimeout(() => { // Connect this to a function instead of a timeout obviously
    AdMobRewarded.showAd()
}, 5000)
```

See the `https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob` plugin for full examples on the code usage.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible to add your own design on banners. I played around a little with reac-native-admob then did some basic work with a similar package from facebook [react-native-fbads](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads). My experience was that the later was a little more flexible. However I don't think they become nicer then the original from admob. But at least you could add the button.